# Как обработать парамеры запуска bash скрипта?

Tags: bash, sh

Подскажите пожалуйста,

каким образом можно обработать параметры запуска bash скрипта?

Например, запускают его так: bash test.sh --path=/bin/temp/rest

Как можно в самом скрипте, получить значение path?

Есть ли инструменты для работы с аргументами, как сокращёнными так и с полным названием ?

Comment: Вот тут решение есть:
[How do I parse command line arguments in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192249/how-do-i-parse-command-line-arguments-in-bash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас два варианта: переносимый и *POSIX*-совместимый
`getopts` (короткие опции) и *GNU*'тый
`getopt` (короткие и длинные опции).  `getopts`:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

path=""
x="0"

while getopts p:x flag
do
    case "$flag" in
    (p)
        path="$OPTARG"
        ;;
    (x)
        x="1"
        ;;
    (?)
        printf "usage: foo.sh [-p path] [-x]" > 2
        exit 2
        ;;
    esac
done

echo path="$path", x="$x"
```

Это позволит вам запускать команду как
`./test.sh -p /foo/bar -x`.  Есть
[хак](https://stackoverflow.com/q/402377/1892060),
чтобы заставить его парсить длинные опции тоже.  Вот вариант
с `getopt`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

path=""
x="0"

opts=$(getopt --options x --long path: -- "$@")

eval set -- $opts

while true
do
    case "$1" in
    (--path)
        path="$2"
        shift
        ;;
    (-x)
        x="1"
        shift
        ;;
    (--)
        shift
        break
        ;;
    (*)
        break
        ;;
    esac
done

echo path="$path", x="$x"
```

Так можно делать `test.sh --path="/foo/bar" -x`.

Ссылки на документацию:

- `getopts`:
  https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/getopts.html.
- `getopt`: 
  http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/getopt.1.html.

Comment: А зачем лидирующая (октрывающая) скобка в каждом из case-ов?

Comment: @0andriy  Это мой стиль.  «Я так вижу» :-D  [*POSIX* разрешает](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04_05).

Comment: вариантов как минимум три (это если не считать множества поделок с гитхаба): можно ведь просто в цикле пройтись по списку аргументов.