# Как распарсить значения из аргументов

Tags: bash, shell

К примеру у меня есть цикл который берет по 1 значению из командной строки

```
while [ -n "$1" ]
do
case "$1" in
парсить вот тут
esac
shift
done
```

аргументы выглядят следующим образом: `name=value`
Пример: `type=Usual`

Вопрос: Как запарсить аргументы и присваивать value переменной с таким же name

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как обработать парамеры запуска bash скрипта?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1052506/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0-bash-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b0)

Comment: `name=value ваш.скрипт` и не надо ничего парсить.

Comment: всмысле? Если можно, то объясните подронее.

Comment: объясняю подробно: в командной строке набираете `name=value`, затем пробел, затем `./ваш.скрипт` (если ваш скрипт находится в текущем каталоге). потом нажимаете клавишу enter. после этого ваш скрипт будет интерпретирован и среди переменных окружения, ему доступных, будет переменная `name` со значением `value`. вы всё поняли?

Comment: вроде да, спасибо